# Структура с ключами в SQL SERVER

Tags: sql, sql-server

Не могу понять как создать структуру базы данных с ключами как на скрине. Для загрузки только уникальных значений в базу inn_producer.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Какими запросами можно создать аналогичную?

Comment: У вас есть доступ к этой БД? Если да, то просто посмотрите в ней самой код создания.

Comment: Доступ есть. А как это сделать.

Comment: Правый клик на таблице: Script As. Также правый клик на ключе или индексе.

Comment: Спасибо. Нашел.